# задачка на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать программу, в которой вводим из клавиатуры текст из букв и цифр 
и она должна посчитать, сколько в тексте букв и цифр и вывести их на экран.

```
s = input("введите текст:")
a = 0
b = 0
for i in s:
    if i == str:
        a += 1

    elif i == int:
        b += 1
print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s = input("введите текст:")
a, b = 0, 0 
for i in s: 
    if i.isdigit(): 
        a += 1 
    else: 
        b += 1
print('str - {}, num - {}'.format(b, a))
```

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы *сравнивали элемент строки с типом данных*, которым ни один элемент ясное дело не является, да и то, даже если бы вы сделали так - `if type(i) == str`, все равно получилась бы ошибка, т.к любой элемент **строки** имеет тип **строки**, даже если это число

Answer (score 2):

Я немножко изменил ваш код, чтобы он работал

```
s = input("Введите текст: ")

a = 0
b = 0
for i in s:
    if i.isdigit():
        a += 1
    else:
        b += 1

print("Цифр:", a)
print("Букв:", b)
```

*Тест:*

> ```
> Введите текст: a1b23Ц456
> Цифр: 6
> Букв: 3
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с использованием библиотеки `re`:

```
import re
string = input('Введите строку: ')
a = re.findall(r'\D', string).__len__()
b = re.findall(r'\d', string).__len__()
print(f'Цифр: {b}\nБукв: {a}')

# Введите строку: ваывау43234235еуацккцк
# Цифр: 8
# Букв: 14
```

> Если нужно исключить знаки препинания то можно использовать:
>   `a = re.findall(r'[a-zа-яё]', string, re.I).__len__()`

Comment: а для чего нужно .__len__() ?

Comment: @finally, `re.findall` дает объект `list` каждым элементом которого является соответствующая шаблону регулярного выражения строка. В данным случае, шаблоном регулярного выражения задано - каждый единичный символ входящий в диапазон заданный между квадратными скобка в шаблоне. Соответственно длина списка (то-есть количество элементов в списке) и будет равно искомому значению. Это выражение эквивалентно `len(re.findall(r'[a-zа-яё]', string, re.I))`

Comment: понял, спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

[Вот источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878174/how-to-count-digits-letters-spaces-for-a-string-in-python) :

```
s = input("введите текст:")

numbers = sum(c.isdigit() for c in s)
words   = sum(c.isalpha() for c in s)
spaces  = sum(c.isspace() for c in s)
others  = len(s) - numbers - words - spaces
```